# HTML 5 Audio Element Not Buffering

Tags: jquery, html5-audio

I have a web page with a list of episodes belonging to a podcast. The list of episodes has a "play" glyphicon next to each episode's title with the MP3 source of the episode set as a "data-value" attribute:

```
<a href="#/">
  <span id="play-episode-1" data-value="https://www.example.com/serial-s01-e01.mp3" data-episodetitle="Episode 01: The Alibi" class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
</a>
```

I have an HTML5 audio element with an empty source attribute on the page as well.

```
<span class="navbar-text audio-control">
  <audio id="player" preload="auto" controls>
    <source id="mpeg-source" src="" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
</span>
```

I use jQuery to respond to the play icon click event by setting the src attribute and playing the episode.

```
 var audio = $("#player");

 $(document).on("click", "[id^=play-episode]", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#mpeg-source").attr("src", $(this).attr("data-value"));
    var title = $(this).attr("data-episodeTitle");
    $(this).attr("class", "glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up");

    audio[0].pause();
    audio[0].load();

    audio[0].addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
        audio[0].play();
    });
```

The problem that I'm experiencing is that when I set the source attribute and start to play the episode it only buffers to a certain point, and once it reaches that point the playback stops, so it seems to me that it's just stopped loading. I've set the preload attribute to auto based on [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) which seems to indicate it should help this problem. My suspicion though is that since the source isn't set on page load the preload attribute makes no difference.

Is there a way to prompt the audio element to load the entirety of the audio file or am I just barking up the wrong tree in this case?

Comment: Looks like the audio file isn't compatible with the browseR?

Comment: I don't think that it's a compatibility issue with the browser.  Playback starts, but it stops after playing for some indeterminate amount of time.  If I'm not mistaken, playback shouldn't even start if the file is incompatible.  I've tested this primarily in Chrome which according to [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mp3) indicates that MP3 files shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: What happens if you try to skip ahead in the audio track while it's still playing?

Comment: @idbehold It will usually pick up playback at the point you've skipped to and start to load more of the file from there.  However that's not to say that the rest of the file is loaded once you've skipped ahead and everything works as it should, playback will sometimes still just stop as if the file is no longer being loaded even after skipping ahead.

Comment: Is your server generating some kind of unique URL designed for a single playback or something? Or is it really just a static URL?

Comment: @idbehold I'm not generating any URL, I get the destination of the MP3 file from a web service along with other metadata about the podcasts/episodes.  I suppose it is possible that what that service is returning to me is a URL generated for a single playback, but I do not know.  I will check with the developers on the service.